# Retrieving only highlighted solr field and not the whole content

Tags: solr, solr4

I wanted to index pdf, word documents using solr. The whole content of the word / pdf document is coming in the search response and also the highlighted fragment. The content is quite long and I wanted avoid it in the search response because of the content length.

Is it possible to get only the highlighted fragment of the content field ?

Here is the search query

`http://localhost:8080/solr4x/collection1/select?q=Scripting&wt=xml&hl=true&hl.fl=content`

Here is the schema

`<field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true"multiValued="true"/>`

`<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>`

```
 <copyField source="content" dest="text"/>
```

I am using solr 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify in your request url which fields you want returned:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr4x/collection1/select?q=Scripting&wt=xml&hl=true&hl.fl=content&fl=text
```

[SOLR field parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl)

Or you could not store the content field (although not sure about the usefulness of a field which is neither stored nor indexed):

```
<field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding **&hl.fragsize=100**(fragment size) to your query. By default it should be 100, but i am not sure why it is pulling full content for you. Will have to look at your solrconfig.xml for that.

Try changing your search query to:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr4x/collection1/select?q=Scripting&wt=xml&hl=true&hl.fl=content&hl.fragsize=100
```

Here is documentation on fragsize: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.fragsize